# Show button only on selected Item of a ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm creating a Listview in MAUI-Xamarin and I want to show a button to view more details in the selected line. But only in the selected line.

Edit: The question is how to show the button when an item is selected and hide it when it is not.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="44"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Label Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>

          <Button x:Name="btnViewDetails"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="View"
            CornerRadius="50"
            IsVisible="{Binding "WHEN THIS LINE IS SELECTED"}}"/>

        </Grid>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'v tryied using Converter and DataTrigger but i couldn't manage to pass the selected item as parameter

Comment: add CommandParameter ="{Binding .} 
this will give you the button that was pressed ( selected ). beside this, you did't add click event on the button pressed

Comment: I'm asking how to show the button when an item is selected and hide it when it is not.

Comment: Hi, I've added my answer with a new gif to show effect I get. Please let me know if you still have any questions. Besides, if you think my answer is helpful, please consider accepting my answer (click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer). This will help others who have similar issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share two solutions here. And this is the effect I get,

[image]

### Option 1

ListView has **ItemSelected** event. Each time we select an Item, the ListView will invoke this event handler. So we could add some logic in this event handler:

In xaml, add the **ItemSelected** event for ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    ItemSelected="listView_ItemSelected">
```

In code behind then,

```
     MainPageViewModel viewModel;
     public MainPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.BindingContext = viewModel= new MainPageViewModel();

     }

    ...
    private void listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //here we find the corresponding item we select in the ListView
        foreach(Item item in viewModel.Items) 
        { 
            if(e.SelectedItem == item) 
            { 
                item.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                item.IsVisible = false; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Using this way, remember to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** for model Item,

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));

        }
    }

    private bool isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible 
    {
        get
        {
            return isVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            isVisible = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsVisible)));
        }      
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

### Option2

Since you have binded SelectedItem, you could implement the above logic in the Setter of SelectedItem,

```
    private Item selectedItem;
    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedItem = value;
            foreach (var item in Items) 
            { 
                if(selectedItem != item) 
                { 
                    item.IsVisible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.IsVisible = true;
                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

You also have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for model Item.

If you still have any question, feel free to ask me.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It worked! I will be using it for now, but I'm still looking for some that is not dependent on a model property. Thanks!